# Separar palabras de un campo

Tags: sql-server

tengo un campo apellido este campo por lo regular tiene dos apellidos

**MALDONADO VELASQUEZ**

lo que quiero lograr es separarlos, es decir que en un campo me quede apellido 1 y en el otro apellido 2

CAMPO 1 **MALDONADO**
CAMPO 2  **VELASQUEZ**

Logre capturar el primer apellido con este Script, pero el segundo apellido no logro capturar

```
SELECT LEFT(ape_empl, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ',ape_empl ) - 1, -1), LEN(ape_empl))) FROM [dbo].[bi_emple]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tu requerimiento no va más allá de 4 apellidos, lo más sencillo es usar [`PARSENAME()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), reemplazando previamente los espacios por un punto `.`:

```
declare @Apellidos varchar(255) = 'MALDONADO VELASQUEZ'

select  parsename(replace(@Apellidos, ' ', '.') , 1) as Apellido1, 
        parsename(replace(@Apellidos, ' ', '.') , 2) as Apellido2,
        parsename(replace(@Apellidos, ' ', '.') , 3) as Apellido3,
        parsename(replace(@Apellidos, ' ', '.') , 4) as Apellido4


Apellido1 Apellido2 Apellido3 Apellido4
--------- --------- --------- ---------
VELASQUE  MALDONAD  NULL      NULL
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Amigo

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar **LEFT()** como lo estabas haciendo pero combinada con la función **SUBSTRING()** y la función **CHARINDEX()**.

```
SELECT LEFT(ape_empl,CHARINDEX(' ',ape_empl)-1) AS APELLIDO1,
SUBSTRING(ape_empl,CHARINDEX(' ',ape_empl)+1,LEN(ape_empl)) AS APELLIDO2
FROM EMPLEADOS
```

La salida sería:

```
APELLIDO1 | APELLIDO2
MALDONADO | VELASQUEZ
```

**CHARINDEX()** retorna la posición en la cual se encuentra el caracter que le estamos especificando *en este caso, el espacio*. Sería la posición **10**

**LEFT()** selecciona los caracteres que estén a la izquierda y antes del espacio, *por eso el **-1** en la primera línea 10 - 1 = 9* -> **MALDONADO**

**SUBSTRING()** permite pasar una cadena **ape_empl**, especificar cual va hacer la posición desde la cual va a empezar a tomar caracteres **' '+1** *el espacio que está en la posición 10 + 1 = 11* y el ultimo parámetro es la cantidad de caracteres que se van a tomar en cuenta **LEN(ape_empl)** -> **VALENCIA**.

**LEN(ape_empl)** nos retorna la longitud del apellido para así no tener que especificar cuántos caracteres se van a tomar a partir de la posición de la cual se inicia **LEN(ape_empl) = 19**. Se puede definir un valor numérico estático pero es mejor determinar la longitud de la palabra de forma dinámica.

Comment: Muchas gracias el otro script me traía los datos bien pero algunos en NULL  este los trae completos